# Google directions API not optimising way points

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

Steps to reproduce
Add this in an iframe with an API Key

`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=Tyne Tunnel Trade Park, Tyne Tunnel Trading Estate, Unit 3 Narvik Way, North Shields NE29 7DE&destination=Tyne Tunnel Trade Park, Tyne Tunnel Trading Estate, Unit 3 Narvik Way, North Shields NE29 7DE&waypoints=optimize:true|Coxwold Way Billingham TS23 4EA|Aykley Heads Durham DH1 5TS|Crosby Grange Northallerton DL6 3SG&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Doesn't optimize the route instead it adds another waypoint to True Track Software Ltd, Office 9-10, Cauldon Locks, Shelton New Rd, Stoke-on-Trent ST4 7AB, United Kingdom.

Following these steps will guarantee the quickest resolution possible.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the API to me.

Answer (score -1):

Consider filing a [bug report for Directions API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188841&template=787416) or opening a support ticket to have Google investigate the route optimization behavior.